# telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() and subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() both returns different mnc (mobile Network code)

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, cellinfo, android-subscriptionmanager

I'm trying to get the signal strength of dual sims it works absolutely fine on most of the phones but for some phones (same android version [11] but different geographic location) the MNC code what we receive from `subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` and  `telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` does not matches.

I'm fetching the getAllCellInfo by following code

```
 ArrayList<CellInfo> allCellInfo = new ArrayList<>(telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo());
```

allCellInfo values are as follow

```
allCellInfo Size:6
 CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=YES mTimeStamp=76968972213907ns mCellConnectionStatus=0 CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=483863 mPci=231 mTac=154 mEarfcn=38750 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=405 mMnc=866 mAlphaLong=JIO 4G mAlphaShort=JIO 4G mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=2147483647 rsrp=-100 rsrq=-13 rssnr=0 cqi=2147483647 ta=6 level=2 parametersUseForLevel=0 android.telephony.CellConfigLte :{ isEndcAvailable = false }}
 CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=NO mTimeStamp=76968972213907ns mCellConnectionStatus=0 CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=0 mPci=66 mTac=0 mEarfcn=38750 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=null mMnc=null mAlphaLong= mAlphaShort= mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=2147483647 rsrp=-100 rsrq=-14 rssnr=0 cqi=0 ta=0 level=2 parametersUseForLevel=0 android.telephony.CellConfigLte :{ isEndcAvailable = false }}
 CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=YES mTimeStamp=76969000601292ns mCellConnectionStatus=0 CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=109569537 mPci=0 mTac=9020 mEarfcn=1250 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=405 mMnc=753 mAlphaLong=Vi India mAlphaShort=Vi India mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-59 rsrp=-111 rsrq=-9 rssnr=-2 cqi=2147483647 ta=0 level=1 parametersUseForLevel=0 android.telephony.CellConfigLte :{ isEndcAvailable = false }}
 CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=NO mTimeStamp=76969000601292ns mCellConnectionStatus=0 CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=0 mPci=67 mTac=0 mEarfcn=1250 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=null mMnc=null mAlphaLong= mAlphaShort= mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=2147483647 rsrp=-111 rsrq=-16 rssnr=0 cqi=0 ta=0 level=1 parametersUseForLevel=0 android.telephony.CellConfigLte :{ isEndcAvailable = false }}
 CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=NO mTimeStamp=76969000601292ns mCellConnectionStatus=0 CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=0 mPci=33 mTac=0 mEarfcn=1250 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=null mMnc=null mAlphaLong= mAlphaShort= mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-59 rsrp=-112 rsrq=-11 rssnr=0 cqi=0 ta=0 level=1 parametersUseForLevel=0 android.telephony.CellConfigLte :{ isEndcAvailable = false }}
 CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=NO mTimeStamp=76969000601292ns mCellConnectionStatus=0 CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=0 mPci=403 mTac=0 mEarfcn=1250 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=null mMnc=null mAlphaLong= mAlphaShort= mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-59 rsrp=-117 rsrq=-16 rssnr=0 cqi=0 ta=0 level=0 parametersUseForLevel=0 android.telephony.CellConfigLte :{ isEndcAvailable = false }}
```

subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() is fetched like bellow

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    subManager = (SubscriptionManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
    activeSubscriptionInfoList = subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
}
```

activeSubscriptionInfoList values are as follow

```
activeSubscriptionInfoList Size:2
 {id=2 iccId= simSlotIndex=0 carrierId=2018 displayName=Jio 4G carrierName=Jio 4G nameSource=0 iconTint=-13408298 number= dataRoaming=1 iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@58bcc24 mcc=405 mnc=856 countryIso=in isEmbedded=false nativeAccessRules=null cardString= cardId=1 isOpportunistic=false groupUUID=null isGroupDisabled=false profileClass=-1 ehplmns=null hplmns=null subscriptionType=0 groupOwner=null carrierConfigAccessRules=null areUiccApplicationsEnabled=true}
 {id=1 iccId= simSlotIndex=1 carrierId=1963 displayName=Vodafone IN carrierName=Vi India | Vodafone IN nameSource=1 iconTint=-16746133 number= dataRoaming=0 iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@c91138d mcc=405 mnc=67 countryIso=in isEmbedded=false nativeAccessRules=null cardString= cardId=0 isOpportunistic=false groupUUID=null isGroupDisabled=false profileClass=-1 ehplmns=null hplmns=null subscriptionType=0 groupOwner=null carrierConfigAccessRules=null areUiccApplicationsEnabled=true}
```

from above example you can see that I have two sim cards in the device which is fetched by the activeSubcriptionInfoList, `with MNC 856 for simSlot 0` and `MNC 67 for simSlot 1`.

But you can clearly see that allCellInfo does not have `MNC 856` and `MNC 67`, instead it has `MNC 866` and `MNC 753`

How to solve this issue ? how to map the CellInfo list to simSlot 0 and SimSlot 1 with different MNC values ?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the array index of cellinfo to map it to the simSlot 0/1,

created the new list of to store only the registered Cellinfo

```
ArrayList<CellInfo> registeredCellinfo = new ArrayList<>();
  for (CellInfo rcinfo : allCellInfo) {
    if (rcinfo.isRegistered()) {
       registeredCellinfo.add(rcinfo);
    }
 }
```

then to get the simSlot 0 / simSlot 1 CellInfomation im returning the registredCellInfo element at the specified simSlot, (registeredCellInfo elements are ordered, simSlot 0 information will be in the index 0)

```
 return registeredCellinfo.get(slotIndex);
```